# Unable to install flowmepy

Tags: python

I am trying to install flowmepy package (https://pypi.org/project/flowmepy/).

- OS: Linus
- Python Version: 3.8, 3.9, 3.10

All the combinations produce the same error (see below)

```
> Collecting flowmepy   
> Using cached flowmepy-0.2.16.tar.gz (22 kB)  
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done 
> Requirement already satisfied:numpy>=1.17.4 in c:\users\anaconda3\envs\selfx\lib\site-packages (from flowmepy)(1.22.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.24.2 in > c:\users\anaconda3\envs\selfx\lib\site-packages (from flowmepy) (1.4.3) 
> Collecting cmake!=3.16.3 (from flowmepy)   
> Using cached cmake-3.26.4-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (33.0 MB) 
> Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\anaconda3\envs\selfx\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.24.2->flowmepy) (2.8.2) 
> Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\anaconda3\envs\selfx\lib\site-packages (from > pandas>=0.24.2->flowmepy)(2022.1)
> Requirement already satisfied:six>=1.5 in c:\users\anaconda3\envs\selfx\lib\site-packages (from python dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=0.24.2->flowmepy) (1.16.0) 
> Building wheels for collected packages: flowmepy 
> Building wheel for flowmepy> (setup.py) ... error   
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> 
> × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   
> │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [60 lines of output]
>       running bdist_wheel
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\flowme
>       copying src\flowme\loader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\flowme
>       copying src\flowme\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\flowme
>       running build_ext
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-brzesgci\flowmepy_570ec4ec61af43218c02f2c1e91bd137\setup.py", line 39, in run
>           out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\subprocess.py", line 421, in
> check_output
>           return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
>           with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
>           self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in
> _execute_child
>           hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
>       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>      
>       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>      
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
>         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
>         File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-brzesgci\flowmepy_570ec4ec61af43218c02f2c1e91bd137\setup.py", line 124, in <module>
>           setup(
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py",
> line 107, in setup
>           return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py",
> line 185, in setup
>           return run_commands(dist)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py",
> line 201, in run_commands
>           dist.run_commands()
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py",
> line 969, in run_commands
>           self.run_command(cmd)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
> line 1244, in run_command
>           super().run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py",
> line 988, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py",
> line 325, in run
>           self.run_command("build")
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py",
> line 318, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
> line 1244, in run_command
>           super().run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py",
> line 988, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py",
> line 131, in run
>           self.run_command(cmd_name)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py",
> line 318, in run_command
>           self.distribution.run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py",
> line 1244, in run_command
>           super().run_command(command)
>         File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\selfX\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py",
> line 988, in run_command
>           cmd_obj.run()
>         File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-brzesgci\flowmepy_570ec4ec61af43218c02f2c1e91bd137\setup.py", line 41, in run
>           raise RuntimeError("CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: " +
>       RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: FlowMePy
>       [end of output]
> 
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for flowmepy  
> Running setup.py clean for flowmepy Failed to build flowmepy ERROR:
> Could not build wheels for flowmepy, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Some repositories that have utilized this module indicate that it works only for Windows (see: https://github.com/mwoedlinger/flowformer). However, I am unable to install it anyway.

What to do?

Comment: Please include the complete error message

Comment: Should have worked at least on win64 and python 3.8. maybe share the error message for that combination. Make sure that the python version is exactly what you think it is, i.e. call pip with `python -m pip` where `python --version` gives 3.8

Comment: Error message updated. It doesn't make much sense to me, although.

Comment: Please put the error message in code formatting, not as a quote. It is highly unreadable in this way. After pasting it into the editor, select the complete erorr message and hit the `{}` button

Comment: Current error message is from 3.10.

Comment: flowmepy https://pypi.org/project/flowmepy/#files has only one whl file for python 3.8. For all other versions it installs from source. Do you get the same error message when you try to install on python 3.8?

Comment: I tried for 3.8 on windows, and it works. Thanks!

Comment: From your question, I would have assumed that you had tried that already, but glad it works now. A Tip for the future: If you want to install a package, first look on `anaconda.org` if it is available for `conda install`, then check on `pypi`. If you are having trouble, check the `files` tab on pypi to see for which python versions that package has whl files

Comment: Perhaps I tried all of those (3.8, 3.9, 3.10) in Linux, but none worked.